# Reverse Tether - Share OSX Yosemite Wifi Connection Over Bluetooth

Tags: macos, bluetooth, android, tethering

I see plenty of old questions out on the web, but each has a myriad of people following up with issues. Now with Yosemite, I think things might have changed anyway.

I want share hotel internet, from my 10.10.3 machine's Wifi connection over bluetooth to my phone. i.e. reverse tether. [This tutorial](http://kiskeyix.org/articles/552) explains in step 2 to enable "Share my internet connection with other bluetooth devices", under "Advanced bluetooth settings". Well, in Yosemite this isn't there.

[image]

In any case, I can pair my device, enable internet sharing in OSX and connect via PAN. But I can't seem to get internet on my phone. How can this be done in Yosemite?

Note: My phone is a S5 on Lolipop. When pairing I can even select my MBP and choose to "Use for internet access".

Edit: To rule out Lollipop I tried all this with my wife's S4 on Kitkat and it couldn't browse either.

Edit2: I have the same issue as [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/137345/55540). Setting the IP of the PAN to DHCP with manual address makes the PAN network show green (it was orange). However, internet on my Android still does not work.

Answer (score 9):

In order to do this in Yosemite, you'll need to go back to the main screen of System Preferences and click on the Sharing preference pane. In the sidebar, there will be an Internet Sharing option. Click on this to view its settings.

Now set the "Share your connection from" drop down to Wi-Fi and then check the Bluetooth PAN checkbox in the menu below. Next just make sure to check the box next Internet Sharing in the sidebar.

Once this is done your Mac should be sharing its Wi-Fi connection to devices in your Bluetooth PAN.

Comment: For people that don't have Bluetooth PAN in their internet sharing list - go to Network settings first and click the plus in the bottom left to add Bluetooth PAN, after that it should be available in the internet-sharing options.

Comment: Thanks for thehelp but I tried that already - `In any case, I can pair my device, enable internet sharing in OSX and connect via PAN`

Comment: Note that an iPhone (even 6s) cannot connect to Internet via Bluetooth PAN. You cannot connect an iPhone to your iMac/Macbook to use OS X Internet connection.

Comment: Why not, @MoOx?

Comment: Because it's not supported by OS X :(

Comment: @MoOx more like.. It's not supported by iOS....

Comment: I did all of that (with an Android 5.1.1 phone and Mac OS X 10.11.4) but it didn't work. The phone could be paired with the laptop, but the internet connection is not shared. And yes, I did switch on the "Internet access" option under the "Use for:" heading in Preferences -> Bluetooth (-> <right_click_on_my_macs_name>). Under Android 6.0.1 I cannot even pair it with the Mac anymore... quite frustrating